# how to keep dependency in testng in different classes webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a scenario like two different test classes, second test class result depends on the first one

public class class1
    {
        @test
        public void sometest1()
        {
            // some functionality
        }
    }

```
public class class2
{
    @test
    public void sometest2()
    {
        // some different functionality
    }
}
```

Here class2 need to be executed if class1 result is pass else class2 needs to be failed.(if no provision for the same i need to execute the test1 in class1 to be executed always first in selenium grid parallel run)

Answer (score 2):

As said avoid please refer :http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations.

As per above comments, i hope you are trying use depends on for method which is in another class. In such a case you need to provide complete path ie package.class.method.

class1:

```
public class testingcode {


@Test
public void test1(){
    System.out.println("test1");
}
}
```

Class2:

```
public class testcase1{

@Test(dependsOnMethods={"com.test.testingcode.test1"})
public void testcase1result() throws InterruptedException{

    System.out.println("test");
}
}
```

Run from TestNG.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none" preserve-order="true">
<test name="Test">
<classes>
  <class name="com.test.testingcode"/>
  <class name="com.test.testcase1"/>
</classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Let me know, if it is not working..

Thank You,
Murali

Answer (score 0):

**You can use dependsOnMethods** like below

```
   @Test
   public void test1() {
       // Instantiate another case class 
       // Call your testcase
   }      

  @Test(dependsOnMethods="test1")
   public void test2() {
   }
```

Comment: thnaks for your time, but the problem is we are using custom tool, to update the results there we need to use different classes only , if it is on the same class above proposed solution will help me , but my case is with different classes

Comment: For that you need to create a main kind of test class, where you need to call other test cases manually. For example instantiate and call you test class inside  test1 and then inside test2 and so on.  See my answer edited

Hope this will work for you. If this helps ,please up vote or accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

There are some annotations in testng that allows you the flow that you want.
I have never worked on testng but I think you can find the suitable annotation here :http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations

might be dependsOnGroups help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use groups and dependency in testng to run a test after some test have executed. There is no way(atleast to my knowledge) to fail the Class2 test if Class1 test failed.

```
public class Class1Test {
    @Test(groups="RunFirst")
    public void sometest1() {
        Assert.fail("just to skip the other test");
    }
}

public class Class2Test {
    @Test(dependsOnGroups="RunFirst")
    public void sometest2() {
        System.out.println("I am running");
    }
}
```

Here the Class2Test will run after Class1Test has run and will be skipped if Class1Test failed.